# Access AWS lambda function via elastic ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, elastic-ip

Is it possible to ping an AWS [elastic IP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#eip-basics) and have it invoke an AWS [lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) without involving a server?

Comment: Why would you want to ping an elastic ip, then invoke a lambda based on response? Can you provide some more details on what you are trying to accomplish? :)

Comment: My business domain requires I have a publicly accessible host that is NOT on AWS. The non-aws host has 3 loadbalancers that redirect traffic to a static IP address. I need that static IP address to invoke a lambda.

Comment: So, why the ping? You can invoke lambda from a server that is not on AWS. I think I might be missing something?

Comment: Your not missing anything; my question stated without "involving a server".

Comment: I guess I associate static ips with a server because in AWS static ips that are exposed to customers involve servers. Serverless infrastructure, like lambda is not serverless, just the servers are abstracted away from the users... so serverless.

Comment: I agree @j-u-s-t-i-n. I was more unsure if there was solution at the  networking layer. Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible. An Elastic IP can only be assigned to an EC2 instance. The Elastic IP is not usable in any other way.

Comment: Can you use VPC to do what?

Comment: Is there a way to use VPC with NAT perhaps?

Comment: To do what exactly, to call a Lambda function? No. You can only call a Lambda function via API Gateway, or directly through the AWS API. Neither of those services run inside your VPC.

Comment: @MarkB - you are correct, but is that what he is asking? Sounds like he just wants to invoke lambda from another server, which is not on AWS. Which is  possible - not really clear on the question here...

Comment: @j-u-s-t-i-n he specifically said in his question "without involving a server". Obviously if he is OK using a server then the question becomes silly and trivial.

Comment: @MarkB - agree. but his comment "my business domain requires I have a publicly accessible host that is NOT on AWS. The non-aws host has 3 loadbalancers that redirect traffic to a static IP address. I need that static IP address to invoke a lambda."  I assume this static ip is a server, but that's an assumption based on lack of context in the question.  Then again, not sure why 3 load balancers would all balance to the same static ip.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB I wasn't confident I could just needed someone with more expertise to confirm for me.

Comment: @j-u-s-t-i-n I asked a technical question. You are trying to answer business related questions. I gave you additional context as you asked for it. You don't need to understand the business domain to offer an answer to my technical question, which is what MarkB did very well.

Comment: @Globalz no need to be rude. Your question is very confusing and your explanation was also confusing. It is very common in these scenarios to ask for clarifying information so that we can help you with the actual problem you are trying to solve, since your question sounds to us like you are starting down the wrong path.

Comment: @MarkB I disagree, However like I said to j-u-s-t-i-n thanks for taking the time to respond.